# Xcode 4 Organizer window does not show app built from the IDE

Tags: ios4, xcode4, xcode-organizer

I am trying to get some files that were created by the app I am working on from my device, in which case I would simply click the Download button next to the app in the Organizer window.

However, for some reason the app that I am building and running on the device from Xcode does not show up in the Organizer window.  My device shows up on the left, I select Applications below my device, and it shows me the other 5 apps that I have built and put on the device from Xcode, just not the app that I need.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, iOS 5.0.1 on the device.  I can't see the app in the organizer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem with Organizer is but a workaround may be to use another tool like http://www.macroplant.com/iphoneexplorer/

Comment: Thanks, at least I was able to get the files I needed using that application. It seems like a nice tool, and you can't beat the price. BP